# Android proper wearkReference Use

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, weak-references

Since weakreferences are garbage collected very easily, is it a bad ideato assign the instance of a weakreference to a scope variable, or should the weakReference's `get()` method be called each time?

```
public class someAsyncExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Activity activity;
    private Toast toast;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Activity activity;

    public someAsyncExample(WeakReference<Activity> activity) {
        this.activity = activity.get();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        toast = new Toast(activity, "Done", TOAST.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your reason for using a WeakReference in the first place here?  Why not just pass the Activity reference directly?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html The developers blog indicates that to avoid context-related memory leaks, weak references should be passed instead

Comment: Deleting my previous post-  it applied to using them to cache data.  For context passing it still makes sense, but you should absolutely use get each time-  if you save it to a class level variable you have the same problem.  Assigning it to a method scoped variable is fine though.

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately cannot officially accept your answer in the form of a comment

Comment: One more thing, would it make sense to make a class-level WeakReference variable, assign its instance to the one passed int he constructer and call the get() method for the class-level weakreference for all cases?